# What are the specific Necromancer-only spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

The [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Necromancer#Necromancer_Spells) lists these Necromancer spells:

> - Conjuration (both major): 2 Summon (Ghost, Skeleton, Zombie), of which 1 of the best possible level.
> - Destruction (minor and major): 1 Damage Health, Drain Health, Fire Damage, Frost Damage or Shock Damage (the damage spells may all be on touch or on target) and a second, more powerful, one with same effects plus Disintegrate Weapon and Armor.
> - Restoration (major): Restore Health.

And while the Conjuration and Restoration spells can be guessed at with the [UESP Spells List](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Spells), the Damage and Disintegrate combination Destruction spells aren't listed even as "Not available in game", so what are the effects of the spells they're using? How much damage do they do, and how quickly?

Necromancers are unlike the monsters, such as [Imps](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Imp), whose spell repertoire *is* listed, like:

> Flare (Fire Damage 6pts on Target)